# Bash script to reorganize files based on part of their file name. Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to reorganize a directory. A script previously was set to go through and convert WAVs to MP3s and then move them into a dated folder. The problem is that this script didn't care what day the file was created on vs the day the script was running. The date the script ran is the date the folder files were moved into. This part of the problem I can fix. The part I'm struggling with is reorganizing past files.

Luckily the files have the date they were created in the file name.

How do I dissect the file names to pull the date out? Ex: I have some files in a 2015-12-16 folder that instead need to be in 2015-12-15.

Example file name:

Bad location - /var/spool/folder/**2015-12-16**/qt1-**20151215**-123456-server-1234567890.12345.wav.mp3

I can grab an array of all files that need to be reorganized. Their destination folder will be a dated folder in the format:

Desired - /var/spool/folder/**2015-12-15**/qt1-**20151215**-123456-server-1234567890.12345.wav.mp3

The numbers, naming, etc match what is on the file. All files start with 'qt1-YYYYMMDD'

Comment: You are expected to make an attempt at solving your own problem before you ask about it here. Please show any attempts you've made and what failed about them.

Comment: `mv /var/spool/folder/2015-12-16/*20151215* /var/spool/folder/2015-12-15/.`?

Comment: @jesse-sielaff. Had used `cut` before and completely forgot about it. Thanks, that should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a reverse cut:

```
#Reorganize all newly created mp3s
printf "Reorganize all mp3s created in the last 60 minutes \n"
for f in $(find /var/spool/folder -name '*.mp3' -type f -cmin -60)
    do
            #Recorded date is stored in file name.
            YEAR=$( printf "$f" | rev | cut -d'-' -f4 | cut -c5-8 | rev)
            MONTH=$( printf "$f" | rev | cut -d'-' -f4 | cut -c3-4 | rev)
            DAY=$( printf  "$f" | rev | cut -d'-' -f4 | cut -c1-2 | rev)

            DATE="$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY"

            #Check if dated folder exists. If not, create it.
            if [ ! -d "/var/spool/folder/$DATE" ]; then
                    printf "Creating directory /var/spool/folder/$DATE \n"
                    mkdir /var/spool/folder/$DATE
            fi

            if [ $( printf "$f" | rev | cut -d'/' -f3 | rev) != "folder" ];   then
                    #Move file to the appropriate folder.
                    printf "Moving $f to /var/spool/folder/$DATE \n"
                    mv $f /var/spool/folder/$DATE
            fi

done
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution in the [TXR language](http://nongnu.org/txr) would look something like:

```
@(next :list @(glob "/var/spool/folder/*/*.mp3"))
@(repeat)
@  (all)
@*origdir/@basename
@  (and)
/var/spool/folder/@nil-@nil-@nil/qt1-@{year 4}@{month 2}@{day 2}-@nil.wav.mp3
@  (end)
@  (do
     (bind dir `/var/spool/folder/@year-@month-@day`)
     (unless (equal origdir dir)
       (ensure-dir dir)
       (rename-path `@origdir/@basename` `@dir/@basename`)))
@(end)
```

Basically we use the `glob` function to generate a list of paths by globbing the filesystem. Then we text-scrape this list as if it were a file, using a pattern to match just paths which have the structure we are interested in, while simultaneously breaking them down into `origdir` and `basename`. When we get a match, we form the target directory based on the extracted date and ensure that it exists, then move the file there.

Files which don't match the pattern are skipped. If we expect everything that `glob` finds to match the pattern, we can enforce no skipping like this:

```
@(repeat :gap 0)
```

Now the stream of lines must be matched by the body of the repeat without any gaps (no lines skipped to search for a match). The script will still do the moves for any matching paths, but fail upon hitting the first nonmatching path.

I would first try it with this the `rename-path` changed to this, to have a "dry run":

```
(pprint `rename @origdir/@basename -> @dir/@basename`)
```

I don't have your data.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue

instead of all the `cut`s to extract the date you can simply use

```
awk -F/ '{split($NF,a,"-"); print a[2]}'
```

e.g.

```
$ echo "/var/spool/folder/2015-12-16/qt1-20151215-123456-server-1234567890.12345.wav.mp3" 
    | awk -F/ '{split($NF,a,"-"); print a[2]}'                

20151215
```

you can add the format easily with

```
var=$(awk ...); echo ${var:0:4}-${var:4:2}-${var:6}
```

or with `sed`

```
... | sed -r 's/(....)(..)(..)/\1-\2-\3/'
```

or change the script as

```
$ echo ... | awk -F/ -v OFS="-" '{split($NF,a,"-"); 
      print substr(a[2],1,4),substr(a[2],5,2),substr(a[2],7)}'

2015-12-15
```